# How to use this row in Xslt and how to sort the list to get the information come under right channel when transformin to xhtm with xlst

Tags: xml, xslt

I wonder if somebody could help me!

I have 4 files of these http://xmltv.xmltv.se/1.bluemovie.de_2019-10-27.xml

I have merged them from 4 to 1

While creating xslt file I now need to make 4 channels in xslt file

The problem I am having now is to sort these 4 lists so they come under right channel. 
I don´t know if I have to split the lists again or can I just sort them.

Now when I read the values it comes like a huge list.

The problem is how to read this line to extract values for each channel under a row.

```
<programme channel="1.bluemovie.de" start="20191027060000 +0000" stop="20191027080000 +0000">
<title lang="de">Der Voyeur 2</title>
```

I guess if I wont to have the programs under header of the right channel I have write right values from the row I posted.

With other words is there any way to sort the channels using the inforamtion in the code above?

I would really appreciate a littel help

Comment: Please edit your question and show the (combined) input and the expected output (as code, not as link).

Comment: P.S. This seems to be a *grouping* question. Do a search - it's probably the most often asked XSLT question here. Note that answers are different for XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.